# How to open excel from R?

Tags: r, excel, function

Maybe you can help me, I need to open an excel spreadsheet from R. The libraries allow me to export data or create files but they do not open automatically. I want a function in R to avoid the process of going to Start > Programs > Microsoft Excel.

Answer (score 2):

If you truly want to open the file (and not load the contents in R), you can use a shell command like this

```
shell("test.xlsx", wait = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
system("cmd.exe", input="start excel")
```